# In React, I am working on CRUD form, how to pass data to child component and update in parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on CRUD app, where I have the following components

1. DistributionList - that display the list of items (Title and Users)
2. AddDistributionListForm - A form that takes input (TextBox and People Picker)
3. EditDistributionListForm - A form when user select one of the item in distribution list that populates with values and allow user to edit.

I am having problem when user select an item in Distribution List, how to populate the data in the input fields.
The data is coming for the first time and if i click another item in the list, the new values are not getting populated.

```
 this.state.isEditMode
                ?
                <EditDistributionListForm
                  ref="editForm"
                  item={this.state.currentItem}
                  updateItem={this.updateDistributionList}
                  handleCancel={this.handleCancelEdit}
                />
                :
                <AddDistributionListForm
                  addItem={this.addDistributionList}
                  ref="addForm"
                />
```

Comment: You should request to your server/data source by clicked item key (id), then update `EditDistributionListForm`'s `state` (_by returned data_), rest will be handled by React.

Comment: I'm supposing you have some example code you could put in that could then be added to, to get the result you want.

Comment: I am able to populate the data in EditDistributionListForm, which is working for the first time. If i click on another row, the new values are not getting populated as the EditDistributionListForm component is already rendered

Comment: Please create stackblitz demo